# C# .Net Browsers hitting Home/Index without being sent there

Tags: c#, .net, security, browser, web

Just run into a very weird bug I thought I'd share on the off-chance anyone else has run into it / found a solution.

We have a Web Portal product that is set up in a pretty standard flow:-

- When arriving at the site, the User is directed to the Log In page
- Once they log in, a check is made to see if they've accepted the Terms and Conditions. If not, they're sent to the Ts&Cs page.
- If they've accepted the Ts&Cs, or after they agree, they're sent to the main page of the site.

All that works perfectly, or at least it does from a User point of view.

However, one of our Clients wanted some logging added to the system, to keep track of what the Users were doing. So we added that in, including:-

- After logging in, record 'LogOn'
- After accepting Ts&Cs, record 'AcceptedTC'
- When reaching the main page, record 'MainPage'

All of this was tested locally in our Development environment, and works perfectly, for example:-

- User gets to the Log In page: Nothing recorded yet
- User logs in, and gets to the Ts&Cs page: 'LogOn' recorded
- User declines the Ts&Cs, and gets sent back to the start: 'LogOff' recorded
- User logs on again, and gets to the Ts&Cs page: 'LogOn' recorded
- User accepts the Ts&Cs, and gets to the main page: 'AcceptedTC' and 'MainPage' recorded

All well and good, and exactly what we expected, so we rolled it out to the Client sites.

One of the Clients then gets an awkward User, who refuses to accept the Terms and Conditions, so they go to the logs to see how often that User tried to log in.

Every time they tried to log in, there were two entries recorded: 'LogOn' and 'MainPage'. This despite the fact that they insisted that they never reached the main page, and they're still flagged as never having accepted the Ts&Cs.

So we tested it locally, and couldn't reproduce it. We tested it directing their site to our development code to trace everything through, and couldn't recreate it.

However, every time we tried logging on to their Live site, we got the bug.

- Get to the Log In page: Nothing recorded yet
- Log in, and get to the Ts&Cs page: 'LogOn' and 'MainPage' recorded

At no point have we hit the main page, and yet the code to add that logging item is being run. We commented that line out of the main page, and it stopped being logged; we put it back and it started being logged again. Definitely hitting that page, without hitting that page!

Then it got weirder!

If we logged in with Firefox:-

- Get to the Log In page: Nothing recorded yet
- Log in, and get to the Ts&Cs page: 'LogOn' and 'MainPage' recorded

If we logged in with Chrome:-

- Get to the Log In page: Nothing recorded yet
- Log in, and get to the Ts&Cs page: 'LogOn', 'MainPage' and 'MainPage' recorded

If we logged in with Edge:-

- Get to the Log In page: Nothing recorded yet
- Log in, and get to the Ts&Cs page: 'LogOn' recorded

So, Firefox somehow hits a page it isn't on.
Chrome somehow hits a page it isn't on **twice**.
Edge, bizarrely, is the browser that seems to work!

We traced the network traffic of each browser using their Inspector, and none **said** they were going to the main page, or attempting to load it.

The User (them or us) never saw the Main Page, only the Ts&Cs page.

Very weird!

We solved the problem easily enough, by adding a check on the main page to see if the User had accepted the Ts&Cs, and if not redirected them to that page. Visually this did nothing, because the User never sees the main page anyway, they don't get past the Ts&Cs page, but it still fixed the problem of the weird background accesses of that page.

But we never worked out why it was happening, or why the three different browsers all gave different results.

Best theory we came up with was because the main page method was Index on the Home controller, which is the default page for the site, and Firefox and Chrome were doing something in the background, perhaps pre-loading the page?

Nothing was being logged when the User first arrives at the site because the Home controller has an attribute that checks if the User is logged in, and redirects them to the Log In page. Presumably the background process was attempting to pre-load the page, but was being redirected too.

However, on the Terms and Conditions page they're now logged in, and so the Home controller attribute isn't redirecting the background pre-load process away. Adding the 'Not accepted Ts&Cs' test achieved that instead, which is why the solution worked.

That's just a theory, but it holds together from what we've observed.

Whether it's correct or not, both Firefox and Chrome are accessing pages they're not told to access, which could have security concerns beyond our simple Ts&Cs / Logging issue.

Anyone else had this issue? Anyone able to confirm our theory, or correct us as to what's happening?

Spent an hour trying to Google it, but a combination of all the words involved being too generic and Google being too bloated to give decent results these days meant we got nowhere.